# Mapreduce partitioner not working as expected

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I am doing a mapreduce job as followings:
Map Side:
The mapper will output in the form of `A\tB\t\t1` where A and B together is the composite key.

I have used several reducers (reducer is identity reducer, `A -> A` ) in this job, and want to do partition according to the composite key. I run this command to start the mapreduce jobs.

```
hadoop jar hadoop-streaming-2.7.1.jar \
 -D mapred.output.key.comparator.class=org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.KeyFieldBasedComparator \
    -D stream.num.map.output.key.fields=2 \
    -D mapred.text.key.comparator.options="-k1n -k2n" \ 
    -D mapred.text.key.partitioner.options=-k1 \
    -D mapreduce.job.reduces=4 \
    -files /mapper,/reducer \
    -mapper ./mapper \
    -reducer ./reducer \
    -input /data \
    -partitioner org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.KeyFieldBasedPartitioner \
    -output /result
```

What I want for the output is the followings:
Output of Reducer A:

```
A B 1 
A B 1 
A C 1 
A D 1 
A E 1
```

Output of Reducer B:

```
B E 1 
B G 1
E G 1 
B H 1
```

However, the output now is that A as the primary key (A and B in the above case) may appear across different reducers. Any hints for whats happening here ?

Comment: can you please post the definition of your composite key? did you override `hashCode` in there? Or are you just using a concatenated text object?

Comment: @ison did you find a solution to this? I have the same issue.